# How to configure the NetCoreClientGrantConsoleSample in FoxIDs

Tags: oauth-2.0, foxids

How do I configure an application which use OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant like the (NetCoreClientGrantConsoleSample sample) manually in FoxIDs Control Client?
I can only find how the sample is [configured by calling](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/blob/master/tools/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool/SeedLogic/SampleSeedLogic.cs#L320) FoxIDs Control API.

Answer (score 1):

After you have logged into FoxIDs Control Client and selected a track (or created a new track).

1. Go to the `Parties` tab and select the `Down Parties` sub tab
2. Click `Create down-party` and click `OAuth 2.0`
3. Add a Down-party name (Client ID)
4. Add a Redirect URI
5. Select `token` as Response type
6. Add a Secret (copy the secret)
7. Configure access to one or more APIs in Resource and scopes
8. Click Create

This is the NetCoreClientGrantConsoleSample configuration in FoxIDs Control Client
[image]